# increasing entry number automatically for every insert on the entry table

Tags: postgresql

i tried using this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION eno_inc() RETURNS trigger AS $eno_inc$

BEGIN

NEW.eno := OLD.eno + 1;

END;
$eno_inc$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but anytime i run it generates this error:
ERROR:  record "old" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "eno_inc" line 4 at assignment

*** *Error* *****

ERROR: record "old" is not assigned yet
SQL state: 55000

P.S i am very new to SQL

Comment: More complex than needed. I think you just want a SERIAL column in your table.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a

```
RETURN NEW;
```

at the end.

The error

```
ERROR: record "old" is not assigned yet SQL state: 55000
```

does show that this *MIGHT* not be a trigger (OLD and NEW are only used in trigger context). You need to define a trigger for that to work. I suggest you read the [docs about trigger functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE).

As the comment by Steve C notes, make sure you don't just need a [SERIAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) (auto-increment in MySQL terms).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @DrColossos already wrote ..

`OLD` *and* `NEW` are only defined in a trigger **`ON UPDATE`**. In a trigger on INSERT you would get this error message. In a trigger on DELETE you only have `OLD` at your disposal.

Also, for a trigger to work you need a *trigger function* plus a *trigger*. You may be missing that, too. Start by [reading the excellent manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/triggers.html).

But I suspect your problems are more basic than that. First of all, as @Steve commented, you are probably just looking for a [**serial**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column or a [sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createsequence.html) and a DEFAULT to your already existing column.